# 'failed to emit precompiled header' while adding new pod into existing Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I had one project that in Obj-C.

in that I'm facing issue failed to emit precompiled header after adding new pod into Project.

in Project I'm working on both obj-C and swift using Bridging header.

In Pod File, I added the **SendBird**

my Pod File is:

## Podfile

platform :ios, '9.0'

abstract_target 'Virgla' do
  use_frameworks!

```
pod 'ACKategories', :git => 'https://github.com/AckeeCZ/ACKategories.git', :tag => '2.3'    
pod 'FlurrySDK'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

pod 'SSZipArchive'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'MWFeedParser'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage', '1.2'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24' #was 0.20.3
pod 'MagicalRecord', '2.2'
pod 'MSCellAccessory'
pod 'UIAlertView+Blocks'
pod 'RMPickerViewController', '2.0.3'
pod 'Masonry', '1.0.2'
pod 'DateTools'
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.6'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '2.0.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'

pod 'SendBirdSDK'


target 'SoMinn' do
end

target 'GrandAuto' do
end

target 'Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Kiwi'
    # pod 'Kiwi/XCTest'
end
```

**While adding not able to build giving error this**

**1st Error:**

> /Users/narvind/Desktop/Project/Project-Bridging-Header.h:34:9: 'AFNetworking.h' file not found

if I removed this from bridging header then it move to next and go one if I also removed next.

**2nd Error:**

> Failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/narvind/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Virgla-fqsvarxwchjhswedkkofchexhztp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Project_1-Bridging-Header-swift_108K1C1LI14RC-clang_FJJZJV3ZS8XP.pch' for bridging header '/Users/narvind/Desktop/Project/Project_1-Bridging-Header.h'

Comment: I am having this same problem with TwitterKit

Comment: Hi..i am also facing same kind of issue with bridging header.were you able to find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Here‘s my way to solve `failed to emit precompiled header` warning:

in `NetworkingHelper.h`(my networking manager), using `@import AFNetworking;` instead of `#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"`